# Getting the count and unique values of a column of comma separated values?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Supposing all I have is the column A below

```
               +         +
     A         |    B    |    C
+--------------|---------|----------+
               |         |
  X, Y, Z      |   X     |     3
               |         |
  X, Z         |   Y     |     2
               |         |
  X, Y         |   Z     |     2
               +         +
```

How do I generate columns B and C - where the B column grabs the unique elements from A, and the C column generates a count of those values.

Comment: What is the logic behind column B (if first row is correct)?

Comment: Ah sorry for not being more clear. The `B` column grabs the unique elements from A

Comment: How is the value Y represent the unique element in X,Z?

Comment: @EmmadKareem Y doesn't represent the unique element in row 2 containing "X, Z". Column B looks at all the types of values in Column A, and then generates a list of them. And the only types of values in Col A are values that are either X, Y or Z. Tell me if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",A:A),",")&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''",0))`

[QUERY function](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343?hl=en)

[TRANSPOSE function](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094262?hl=en)

[SPLIT function](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094136?hl=en)

[JOIN function](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094077?hl=en)

Comment: Super helpful! Here is a minor modification to the above answer that trims the new lines and whitespace from each of the comma-separated elements: =ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(JOIN(",",A:A),","))&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''",0))

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks! Do you have an idea on how to use the "where" clause that's referencing another column (not A)? I can't seem to figure out how to extend the "date" parameter of the QUERY function.

Answer (score 1):

Without hidden cells is possible to do it with an alternative method than the one proposed by Adam (that did not work in my case).
I have tested it with google spreadsheets (from data coming from a google form using multiple selection answers):

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(", ";A2:A);", ";FALSE)))
```

Explanation goes as follows:

- JOIN to mix all the values from the A column (except A1 that could be
  the header of the column, if not, substitute it by A:A) separated by 
  a coma
- SPLIT to separate all the mixed values by their comas
- TRANSPOSE to transformate the column into rows and viceversa
- UNIQUE
  to avoid repeated values

*Take into account that my "," coma includes and space character i.e., ", " to avoid incorrect unique values because "Z" y not equal to " Z".*

Comment: This does not work if you have a lot of data (you hit the 50000 char limit on join)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to create a hidden sheet?

If yes, 1) use the `SPLIT()` function to separate the values into columns and 2) use `COUNTIF()` on the hidden sheet to get the number of values