# How do I count occurrences of a word over many rows with Google Spreadsheet

Tags: count, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet like this:

```
|     A     |    B   |        C        |
+-----------+--------+-----------------+
| Date      | Place  | Names           |
+-----------+--------+-----------------+
| 1/2/2013  | Place1 | John, Jane, Bob |
| 2/5/2013  | Place2 | Jane, Doug      |
| 3/8/2013  | Place3 | John, Jane      |
| 4/15/2013 | Place4 | Doug, Mark, Bob |
```

I want, in another sheet, to count the number of times a name (or word, basically) appears in column C on Sheet1, but the list needs to be dynamic. I could easily do a `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!C:C, "*John*")` to return 2, but then I have to do that for every person who appears in column C. So I first need to obtain a list of unique names in column C, split by comma, then do a count on each of those names and print them out alphabetically to look like this:

```
|     A     |   B   |
+-----------+-------+
| Name      | Count |
+-----------+-------+
| Bob       |   2   |
| Doug      |   2   |
| Jane      |   3   |
| John      |   2   |
| Mark      |   1   |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the count and unique values of a column of comma separated values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715099/getting-the-count-and-unique-values-of-a-column-of-comma-separated-values)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715099/getting-the-count-and-unique-values-of-a-column-of-comma-separated-values/20722375#20722375); ColA is the Names list; ColB is your name list and ColC is the count

Answer (score -2):

I am not clear about the spreadsheet, but I have alternative solution for your problem.
   What I did, I put that data in simple txt file , I executed following command to getting
   output as per your needs

Linux command : cut -d'|' -f3 ex.txt |  sed 's/,/\n/g'|sort | cut -d' ' -f2 | uniq --count

Note : second cut command to use to remove the leading spaces