# Getting the unique values and counts of them in a column of comma separated values in Google Sheets without using JOIN?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column with a bunch of ingredients lists in it. I'm trying to figure out how many times different individual ingredients appear. There are 73,000 rows. The answers on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715099/getting-the-count-and-unique-values-of-a-column-of-comma-separated-values) works for a small amount of data in Google Sheets.

Formula is `=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(", ";A2:A);", ";FALSE)))`

But I've overwhelmed `JOIN` with more than 50000 characters here. Is there another way to tackle this?

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t0P9hMmVpwhI2IbATmIMjobuALTg8VWhl8-AQaq3zIo/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(","&A1:A,,5000000)),",")))))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=QUERY(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(","&A1:A,,5000000)),",")))),
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''"),
  "order by Col2 desc")
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dwyi6_9hbr1Q56DDiMq5xZ3Esd_QhdeKVjUkPKOUUVo/edit#gid=1540702481)**

Comment: That seems to have done it. Not totally sure. Possible to get counts as well? Also, thanks!

Comment: sure, it's possible... just load time could be tricky (even crash) if you got weak PC. answer updated

Comment: dang...you should offer an online sheets course...amazing work.

Comment: if this helped you then consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(","&A1:A),,5000000))," ,",","),",")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: "Text result of REGEXREPLACE is longer than the limit of 50000 characters." as well

Answer (score 1):

but maybe you need this (?):

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(","&A1:A),,5000000))," ,",","),",")),
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: "Text result of REGEXREPLACE is longer than the limit of 50000 characters." Could be time for me to learn Python/pandas

Comment: nah, there is always a way with formulas

Answer (score 1):

I did a google scripting solution because I wanted to play with key map pairs.

```
function myFunction() {
  var myMap = {"candy":0};
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ss = sh.getSheetByName("FIRSTSHEETNAME");
    var os = sh.getSheetByName("Ingredients");
    var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++)//full
    //for (var i=1; i<4000;i++)//test
      {
      var array = data[i][0].split( ",");
      for (var j=0; j<array.length;j++)
        {
          var item = array[j];
          //Logger.log(array[j]);
          if (myMap[item]>-1){
            //Logger.log("REPEAT INGREDIENT");
            var num = parseInt(myMap[item]);
            num++;
            myMap[item]=num;
            //Logger.log(item +" "+num);
          } else {
            myMap[item]=1;
            //Logger.log("New Ingredient: "+item);
            //Logger.log(myMap);
          }

        }
      }
  //Logger.log(myMap);
  var output=[];
  for (var key in myMap){
    //Logger.log("Ack");
    output.push([key,myMap[key]]);


  }
  //Logger.log(output);
  os.getRange(2,1,output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output);

}
```

You'll need to add an "Ingredients" tab for the output and change your first tab to be called FIRSTSHEETNAME (or change the code). In my testing it took 4 seconds for 4 items, 5 seconds for 400 items, and 6 seconds for 4000 items. there might be an issue with leading spaces but this gives you a place to start.

Comment: I just counted them... there are **1,965,918** items which could take more than 30 seconds (?) in which case script will fail before it's completed

Comment: Did you try it? The script limit is 5 minutes now for non corporate accounts, 30 minutes for corporate accounts. and by items I meant rows.

Comment: I didn't, did you? 5/30min... interesting. I heard 30sec... good to know then. as for the rows, there are: **98,268**

Answer (score 1):

A fast running formula that works with columns of at least 40,000 rows:

```
 =query(arrayformula(TRIM(flatten(split(A2:A20000,",")))),"select Col1,Count(Col1) Where NOT (Col1='' OR Col1 contains '#VALUE!') Group By Col1 order by Count(Col1) desc label Col1 'Ingredient',Count(Col1) 'Freq.'")
```

[FLATTEN function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en), combined with SQL ([QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)) can be a solution for fast filtering of values (such as empty or error messages).

[TRIM function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en) avoids artifacts in the result due to meaningless spaces before/after each string.

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m9EvhQB1Leg2H7L52WhPe66_jRrTc8VsnZcliQsxJ7s/edit?usp=sharing

*In case of false case differences, you could normalize all characters of the strings to uppercase before within the same formula with [UPPER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094219?hl=en)(A2:A20000).