# Count unique comma-separated values in column B based on criteria in column A

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

How do I list and count unique comma-separated values (column B in the example below) if the number in column A is larger (or smaller) than X? In other words, how do I turn the below table...

```
   Day   |          Fruits
+--------|--------------------------+
         |
    20   |   Apple, Banana, Pearl
         |
    24   |   Apple, Pearl
         |
    32   |   Banana, Pearl
         +
```

...into this , with criteria: `Day < 28`.

```
  Fruit    |   Frequency
+----------|---------------+
           |
  Apple    |       2
           |
  Pearl    |       2
           |
  Banana   |       1
           +
```

A solution proposed by @AdamL in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20739148/2052975) is really close to what I want to achieve, but I can't figure out how to list values based on criteria from another column. Here's what Adam came up with:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",A:A),",")&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''",0))
```

Comment: Have you considered doing this in Apps Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))="",,A2:A&"♦"&TRIM(SPLIT(B2:B, ",")))), "♦"),
 "select Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col1 < 28 
    and Col1 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  label count(Col2)''"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bit easier to filter on column A first then split:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(flatten(split(filter(B2:B,A2:A<28,A2:A<>""),",")),"select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Fruit',Count(Col1) 'Count'"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Considering Column 'A' as days and Column 'B' as fruits with row 1 as headers, AdamL's formula works for you with a little tweak as below:

```js
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",B2:B),", ",True)&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''",0))
```

Hope this solves your problem.